# Why is this this line hit in firebug debugger when condition is false?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug

Check out the position of the debugger in this image. Even though `(isAdmin == null && leadLogged == null) == false` as confirmed in the Watch pane in the image, the `createCookie("LeadLogged");` is being called...or at least hit by the firebug debugger. When stepping through the code with the debugger, it does skip over the `fbq('track', 'Lead');` line, which is good, but it is re-setting the cookie again which will re-age the expire date for another 24 hours, which I don't want.

This is FireFox 48.0.2 and Firebug 2.0.17

My code:

```
var isAdmin = readCookie("IsAdmin");
var leadLogged = readCookie("LeadLogged");

if(isAdmin == null && leadLogged == null) {
    fbq('track', 'Lead');
   //set cookie so we don't log the lead again if they refresh or visit this page again within 1 day
    createCookie("LeadLogged", 1, 1);
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**
Well it looks like it is just a nuance in how the debugger steps through visually, but the code is not actually executed. I put an additional cookie write line in after the `createCookie("LeadLogged");` and then have the debugger hit it, but when checking the cookies in dev tools, it was not there. So just a bug of sorts in FireBug I reckon.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the debugger is on that line? If you've changed the file in the dev tools, the _previous_ version of the code might be executed. So, say, if you've removed two lines, you you might be on line 317 in the debugger but that will actually be the `if` statement.

Comment: Regarding your edit: the debugger _should_ be on reporting the line it's on, not any lines that aren't executed. Unless there is indeed a bug, however it'd be a rather weird one.

Comment: @vlaz yep. I did not change the code in dev tools. I also changed the source to add a second cookie write (see update in OP). And refreshed the page and it still hits that new line, though the cookie isn't actually written.

Comment: I guess there is one more way to sanity check it's not going into the `if` - just put the `debugger` statement anywhere inside and remove the breakpoint. Although you can also do a `console.log`, it'd be interesting to see what Firebug does.